# Weighted distribution of child elements in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to create a horizontal layout bound to a list of objects with some information to display. I want the size of the controls in this control to space out to fill the control, like the UniformGrid does. 
The thing is, I do not want the control's widths to be uniformly distributed, but rather weighted, based on a property in the object itself.

I thought an ItemsControl with a custom ItemsPanelTemplate would be a good strategy, because it works fine with a UniformGrid:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding MyResults}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <TextBlock Width="{Binding Weight}" Text="{Binding Weight}" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Bound to the view model:

```
public class MainViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public List<MyTestClass> MyResults { get; set; } = new List<MyTestClass>()
    {
        new MyTestClass() { Weight = 25 },
        new MyTestClass() { Weight = 50 },
        new MyTestClass() { Weight = 25 }
    };
}

public class MyTestClass
{
    public int Weight { get; set; }
}
```

One idea is to switch to an ordinary Grid and use the ColumnDefinitions *-width behavior (like `(25*,50*,25*)` but bound as `Weight*`), but I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be much easier to do with custom `Panel` implementation. I would go with something like this:

```
public class WeightedPanel : Panel
{
    public static double GetWeight(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double)obj.GetValue(WeightProperty);
    }

    public static void SetWeight(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(WeightProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Weight", typeof(double), typeof(WeightedPanel), new PropertyMetadata(1.0));

    private double totalWeight_;
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        totalWeight_ = 0;
        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            totalWeight_ += WeightedPanel.GetWeight(child);
            child.Measure(availableSize);
        }

        return new Size(0, 0);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        double offset = 0;
        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            var weight = WeightedPanel.GetWeight(child);
            var width = finalSize.Width * weight / totalWeight_;

            child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(offset, 0), new Size(width, finalSize.Height)));

            offset += width;
        }

        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
    <local:WeightedPanel>
        <Border local:WeightedPanel.Weight="25" Background="Green"></Border>
        <Border local:WeightedPanel.Weight="50" Background="Red"></Border>
        <Border local:WeightedPanel.Weight="25" Background="Blue"></Border>
    </local:WeightedPanel>
```

Comment: This looks like a really nice solution. But I need horizontal flow. I'm going to try to adapt this to use a horizontal orientation

Comment: I changed the ArrangeOverride to do: { var width = finalSize.Width * weight / totalWeight_;
child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(offset, 0), new Size(width, finalSize.Height)));
offset += width;}. If you update your answer with this I'll be more than happy to accept it as the answer to my question

Answer (score -1):

UniformGrid provides a way to arrange content in a grid where all the cells in the grid have the same size.
I have tried your example with WrapPanel and i think the result is what you need.
So just change UniformGrid to WrapPanel or StackPanel(with Orientation="Horizontal").
See in the screenshot
[WrapPanel](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZFTIQZynuqejSOJdX4J0sMyv2PWbbxx447)

Comment: That is pretty close to what I want, but I want the items to fill the parent container to scale with the window on resize etc. The StackPanel and WrapPanel only allows fixed widths